# Using Linq to Sql, how can I get a particular result from a query?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I want to get the last result returned from this query.  How do I do this?  Last and LastOrDefault aren't supported by Linq to Sql.

```
 var docs = (from d in db.Documents                      
                    where d.Version > 1
                    orderby d.DocumentID
                    select new   
                               {                                     
                                   d.DocumentID,
                                   d.DocTypeID,
                                   d.Name,
                                   d.Version
                               });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse your sort criteria (add `descending`) and use `First` (or `FirstOrDefault` as appropriate).